# MySql 1172 Result consisted of more than one row

Tags: mysql

When I'm trying to "start" the function I'm gettin error (1172 Result consisted of more than one row). I've looked in another sites and threads but nothing. I tried to add LIMIT 1 to SELECT but it returns data only from first row in table. It seem like it is ignoring the PESEL = varpes part. The query itself works fine but in function it doesn't.

Here is code of my function

```
delimiter //
create function fPensja(pesel decimal(11)) returns decimal(11)
begin
declare varpes decimal(11);
declare varpensja decimal(10);
declare varnadgodziny decimal(10);
declare varetat decimal(10);
declare vardodatki decimal(10);

set varpes = pesel;


select Pensja,IloscNadgodzin,Etat,Dodatki
    into varpensja,varnadgodziny,varetat,vardodatki
from gmina.pracownicy
where PESEL = varpes;

return vardodatki;
end
//
```

Comment: You've declared `varpes` as a local variable, so it's using that instead of the column from the table. And since you `set varpes = pesel`, it's true for all rows.

Comment: You're my redeemer. Tahnk you very much

Comment: With `varpes = pesel`, you've made both values the same. Using them in the `WHERE` is the equivalent of using `WHERE 1 = 1`, which is always true; every single row in your table matches that `WHERE` clause, so every single row is returned. If you learn to test your query by running it manually, you'd find this sort of problem easily.